# Haystack - Can't find object with prepared fields

Tags: django, indexing, full-text-search, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I have Blog posts and I'm trying to add comments to the search index but it doesn't work for some reason...
My comments has generic foreign key if it matters.
BTW, it works for the tags.

```
class BlogIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    headline = indexes.CharField(model_attr="headline", null=True)
    body = indexes.CharField(model_attr="body")
    date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date')
    mytags = indexes.MultiValueField()
    mycomments = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_mytags(self, obj):
        return [tag.name for tag in obj.tags.all()]

    def prepare_mycomments(self, obj):
        cur_model = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
        cur_comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=cur_model, object_pk=obj.id)
        return [str(cur_c.content) for cur_c in cur_comments]

    def get_model(self):
        return Snip

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
```

this is my template:

```
{{ object.headline }}
{{ object.body }}
{% for c in object.mycomments %}{{ c }} {% endfor %}
{% for tag in object.tags.all %}{{ tag.name }} {% endfor %}
```

I'm also using drf-haystack if it matters, and this is the serializer:

```
class BlogSearchSerializer(HaystackSerializer):
    class Meta:
        index_classes = [BlogIndex]

        fields = [
            "headline", "body", "date", "mytags", 'mycomments', "content",
        ]
```

When I'm searching with content=XX it doesn't find anything in the comments.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

Your template is wrong - specifically you are doing this:

```
{% for c in object.mycomments %}{{ c }} {% endfor %}
```

`object` in this case is an instance of `Blog`, not an instance of `BlogIndex`. The template engine will fail to find anything like that and will just not do anything. You probably want to do this instead:

```
{% for c in object.comment_set.all %}{{ c }}{% endfor %}
```

Assuming that your comments have a foreign key to the `Blog` item that they are attached to.

You don't actually need to index these separately in `BlogIndex.mycomments` unless you want to do more than just search them (e.g., filtering/faceting).

Comment: The problem is the comment's foreign key is generic foreign key and there fore I can't use comment_set AFAK. Thanks!

Comment: I sort of fixed it, but not entirely. I added `comments = GenericRelation(Comment)` to my blog model and now I can index it and search it using /?content=XX but I can't search only in the comments and I can't display the comments in the result using drf-haystack.

Comment: You could add a method to your `Blog` model, e.g., `get_comments` that does the logic you currently have in `BlogIndex.prepare_mycomments` and returns a set of comments. Then you can access that in the template with `object.get_comments`.

Comment: I fixed it by using this: `def load_all_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.all().select_related()`  but how can I show the comments in the results using drf-haystack (the tags also missing)? meaning, the search is working but the display isn't right.

Comment: Not sure - not familiar enough with DRF.